# Mongodb: Combining two collections to get data based upon the value of a key in other collection -(mongoid - rails4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid

I am trying to get a result set by combining "bolg_post" and "User" doc.

```
blog_post # embeds many comments doc
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId( "55ea003e4102135d9d000677" ),
  "text" : "This is a post about natural beauties of hawaii.. blah blah..",
  "author_id": "345345026743545647567567", # references to User doc id
  "updated_at" : Date( 1441398846696 ),
  "created_at" : Date( 1441398846696 ),
  "comments" : [ 
    { "_id" : ObjectId( "55ea003e4102135d9d000002" ),
      "text" : "Very good article",
      "user_id": "83753iy45735y84934759",
      "updated_at" : Date( 1441400501867 ),
      "created_at" : Date( 1441400501867 )
    }, 
    { "_id" : ObjectId( "345a003e41026743545645454" ),
      "text" : "Hawaii is my fav",
      "user_id" : "55e7668c4102132ea8000066", # references to User doc id
      "updated_at" : Date( 1441400501867 ),
      "created_at" : Date( 1441400501867 )
    } 
  ] 
}

User # has many blog_posts

{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId( "83753iy45735y84934759" ),
  "name" : "John abc",
  "status": "active", # could be inactive, pending, deleted etc.
  "age": 29,
  "updated_at" : Date( 1441400501867 ),
  "created_at" : Date( 1441400501867 )
}

{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId( "55e7668c4102132ea8000066" ),
  "name" : "Lisa xyz",
  "status": "inactive", # could be inactive, pending, deleted etc.
  "age": 24,
  "updated_at" : Date( 1441400501867 ),
  "created_at" : Date( 1441400501867 )
}

{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId( "345345026743545647567567" ),
  "name" : "David uyi",
  "status": "active", # could be inactive, pending, deleted etc.
  "age": 39,
  "updated_at" : Date( 1441400501867 ),
  "created_at" : Date( 1441400501867 )
}
```

I want to get only those blog posts, where its author status is active in User doc.
Same way, I want to get only those comments for a post, those are posted by user whose status is active in user doc

```
{ 
  "blog_id" : "55ea003e4102135d9d000677",
  "text" : "This is a post about natural beauties of hawaii.. blah blah..",
  "author": {
    "author_id": "345345026743545647567567",
    "name" : "David uyi",
    "age": 39
  }
  "updated_at" : Date( 1441398846696 ),
  "created_at" : Date( 1441398846696 ),
  "comments" : [ 
    { "comment_id" : ObjectId( "55ea003e4102135d9d000002" ),
      "text" : "Very good article",
      "user" : {
        "user_id": 
        "name" : "John abc",
        "age": 29
      }
    }
    # here Lisa's comment is not shown as she is inactive
  ] 
}
```

But the catch is I want in pagination, that means, suppose I want only 5 records (limit 0, 5) in per query result.
So the easiest way would be grabbing first 5 blog_post documents. and then take user_id from them and then go to User doc and
then find if those user are active or not. if not, then remove those entries. But this way, I may end up having less than 
5 result set. So how can I do this in one go. Assume that I have 100,00,00 users and 100,000 posts. So it would be bad design
  if I do the way I talked about earlier, not in one go

Comment: I guess you could combine 'skip' and 'limit' methods of mongoid to make a pagination (query all blogs from given user, skip n*5 results, limit to 5 results)

Comment: @jmuet I want it in one query, not writing two separate queries

Comment: AFAIK Mongo does not allow for "joins" of multiple collections; you can query single collection. Alternatively, if 'status' field is not changing often, then maybe you could include it in blog posts as well (along the author id) and make updates in all documents whenever user changes status.